# why do pandas comparison operators not align on index?

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, boolean-logic

I have been tracking down an elusive bug in a complex application which relies heavily on pandas, and finally traced it to a Series ordering issue. Series with differently ordered - but compatible - indexes are not automatically aligned by comparison operators. This is different behavior than for arithmetic operators, and it isn't documented as far as I can tell. The fix is easy - just reindex. My question is why this behavior exists in pandas at all - is it a bug?

```
>>> x = pd.Series({'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}, index=['A','B','C'])
>>> y = pd.Series({'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}, index=['B','C','A'])
>>> x/y
A    1
B    1
C    1
dtype: float64
>>> x==y
A    False
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
>>> x.eq(y)
A    False
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
>>> x==y.reindex(x.index)
A    True
B    True
C    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Just to clarify, which version of pandas are you using?  print(pd.__version__) to check

Comment: This was with 0.15.

Also, sorry it took a while to respond - for some reason I'm not getting emails as I thought I would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the discussion here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1134

this was originally a feature, though the reasons for supporting are not necessary anymore (Series has not been a ndarray subclass for quite a while)

I did try to fix this a while back but it opened a whole host of issues. As always would appreciate a doc note to clarify